# jQuery $(window).blur vs native window.onblur

Tags: javascript, jquery, blur, onblur

What are the advantages of using jQuery's

```
$(window).blur(function() { ... })
```

to attach an event handler versus setting it directly with

```
window.onblur = function() { ... }
```

It seems that the latter is less robust because it only supports one blur handler, and when used with other packages, other code might override the `window.blur` value with another function. However, couldn't this also happen with the jQuery implementation too, which presumably uses `window.blur` as its underlying implementation?

**EDIT:** Several people have also mentioned the `window.addEventListener` alternative, which can be used to add an `'onblur'` event apart from the methods above.

Comment: Interestingly, it seems that Chrome doesn't support `onfocus`/`oblur` and jQuery doesn't seem to work either.

Comment: @Whymarrh I seriously doubt that, I think I tried it not too long ago and I'm about to now. Might have to do with incognito mode.

Comment: jQuery uses `addEventHandler` (or `attachEvent`) internally.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

`$(window).blur(function() { ... })`

Lets you add **one or more** event handlers.

---

`window.onblur = function() { ... }`

Lets you only have **one** event handler handling the blur event.

---

The former uses the jQuery's own event handle mechanism. The call to `.blur()` will delegate to `jQuery.fn.on()` which in turn will delegate to `jQuery.event.add`. This `add()` method will create it's own handler for the given event type and tell `addEventListener()` to call this handler whenever a event of given type is fired. So basically jQuery has it's own way of event handling which relies on `addEventListener()` to execute properly.

The latter is just an attribute which can only contain one value so queueing event handlers is impossible.

I wrote a little demonstration to prove this point: http://jsfiddle.net/GnNZm/1/

Comment: That seems obvious from the API definition. If you could elaborate on why the first option will always be able to attach multiple handlers, even if the second option is overridden, then I'd accept your answer as the correct one.

Answer (score 8):

With the jQuery method, you can attach multiple event handlers. By setting `window.onblur`, you can only have a single handler.

Pure JavaScript also has this: [`window.addEventListener()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget.addEventListener). In fact, i'm sure jQuery uses this internally. ([Yes they do](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/master/src/event.js#L122).)

(EDIT)
The `window.onblur` property is basically a shortcut for setting a single handler. Using `addEventListener()` (or the jQuery wrapper) basically creates a list of event handlers, which all get fired when the event happens. I haven't tested, but i think you can even use the two together. Because it's a list, not a single value, multiple handlers shouldn't interfere with each other. They can also be removed separately or all at once.

jQuery's event handlers, using `on()`, also let you namespace your handlers, to prevent clashes if a plugin removes its handlers. Pure JS doesn't seem to have this easily.

Comment: Scimonster: could you confirm/reference that second statement? I think you're on to something here and your answer actually provides the point that everyone else is missing.

Comment: I added some info to the answer, including a reference that jQuery does use `addEventListener`.

Answer (score 5):

For jquery blur

> The blur event does not bubble in Internet Explorer. Therefore,
>   scripts that rely on event delegation with the blur event will not
>   work consistently across browsers. As of version 1.4.2, however,
>   jQuery works around this limitation by mapping blur to the focusout
>   event in its event delegation methods, .live() and .delegate().

taken from jquery doc https://api.jquery.com/blur/

Also jquery allows you bind multiple event handlers

Answer (score 2):

When you attach an event there is the possibility of overwriting an event already attached to an event handler. This used to happen a lot with window.onload() where different scripts overwrote each others event handlers.

eg:

```
//lightbox.js
window.onload = function() { /* do lightbox stuff */ }

//carousel.js 
window.onload = function() { /* do carousel stuff */ }
```

So the common practice used to be something like this:

```
var existing_event_handlers = window.onload;
window.onload = function(){

    //my event code
    alert('onready fired');

    //call other event handlers after
    existing_event_handlers();
}
```

Using `window.onblur = function() { ... }` still has an advantage because you can specifically dictate if you want your event fired before or after other attached events.

Like many other answers already pointed out jQuery abstracts you from most browser differences. Version before IE9 used attachEvent() rather than addEventListener().