# How do I reassign a Javascript event using jQuery?

Tags: jquery

When I log the click handler in js, (var clickHandler = button.onclick;) it gives the following as expected:

```
clickHandler:function () {
    alert("onclick - original onclick handler");
}
```

However, when I log the jQuery click handler (var clickHandler = jQuery('#button').click;), I get:

```
  clickHandler:function (a,c){c==null&&(c=a,a=null);return arguments.length>0?this.bind(b,a,c):this.trigger(b)}
```

Why the difference? How do I get a handle on the function so I can reassign it to another event, eg. onmousedown?

(I need to reassign an existing js event that I have no control over, so it hasn't been added with jQuery).

```
    <input type="text" name="name_input" id="name_input" />
    <a href="#" id="button">Click</a>
    <script>
        var input = document.getElementById("name_input");
        var button = document.getElementById("button");
        input.onchange = function(event) {
            alert("Change");
        };

        //reassign onclick to onmousedown

        button.onclick = function() {
            alert("onclick - original onclick handler");
        };

        //reassign onmousedown handler
        var clickHandler = button.onclick;
        // var clickHandler = jQuery('#button').click;
        console.log('clickHandler:' + clickHandler);

        button.onmousedown = clickHandler;
    </script>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you want this:

```
var clickHandler = jQuery('#button')[0].click;
```

jQuery([selector]) returns an array.

Answer (score 0):

You can assign the same click handler on more than one event:

```
$('#button').on('click mousedown', function() {
    // do something
});
```

Answer (score 0):

`jQuery('#button').click` is just the method used to set the click event handler, it's used as

```
jQuery('#button').click(event_handler);
```

**But not**

```
jQuery('#button').click = event_handler;
```

So `jQuery('#button').click` won't give you the `event_handler`.

Answer (score 0):

The `button.onclick` is the browsers native implementation of the click handler. See [this raw HTML example](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_button_test) which shows how to assign a click handler without using script tags. See this link for why this is a [bad idea](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5871640/why-is-using-onclick-in-html-a-bad-practice).

When you assign click handlers using jQuery, you're using the jQuery library to assign the click handler function to the button. This is why there was a different output when you printed `jQuery('#button').click`.

I would suggest that you stick with jQuery only and do not mix with calls to native JavaScript to manipulate events, like `button.onclick = function(){};`. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22415296/jquery-window-blur-vs-native-window-onblur)